# Is it possible to implement RTP-based protocol using Google's FlatBuffers library?

Tags: protocols, code-generation, midi, rtp, flatbuffers

I'm especially interested in implementation of RTP-MIDI protocol. The major difficulties could be faced in implementation of bit-fields and non-ordinary MIDI-like timestamps, as I can expect. And maybe if somebody knows already existed open source c++ implementations, please give me a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. As far as I can tell, RTP-MIDI is a very specific encoding. FlatBuffers is not able to emulate existing binary encoding/layout, it has its own encoding which typically does not match other binary encodings, even if the same information is stored.

FlatBuffers can generally be used with any protocol that can transport an opaque payload of bytes. RTP itself (not RTP-MIDI) could potentially be used with FlatBuffer data (after the RTP header).